Curvature form and Curvature tensor in complex vector bundle
Let $X$ be a complex manifold and $\pi:E\rightarrow X$ be a complex vector bundle. A connection on $E$ is a $\mathbb C$-linear operator:
$$\nabla:\mathcal C^\infty(X,E)\rightarrow\mathcal C^\infty(X,\Omega_{X,\mathbb C}^1\otimes E)$$
satisfying the Leibniz rule for $f\in\mathcal C^\infty(X)$ and $s\in\mathcal C^\infty(X,E)$:
$$\nabla(fs)=df\otimes s+f\nabla s\tag1$$
Let $\{e_\alpha\}$ be a local frame of $E$. And $\nabla e_\alpha=\omega_\alpha^\beta e_\beta$. We can write the connection $1$-form in terms of Christoffel symbol,
$$\omega_\alpha^\beta=\Gamma^\beta_{i\alpha}dz^i+\Gamma^\beta_{\bar i\alpha}d\bar z^i\tag2$$
Now, we can extend connection to something called exterior derivative defined on sections of vector bundle valued $k$-forms as follows:
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\mathrm d^\nabla:\mathcal C^\infty(X,\Omega_{X,\mathbb C}^k\otimes E)&\rightarrow\mathcal C^\infty(X,\Omega_{X,\mathbb C}^{k+1}\otimes E)\\
\omega\otimes s&\mapsto \mathrm d\omega\otimes s+(-1)^k\omega\wedge\nabla s
\end{split}
\end{align}
There exists a section $\Theta\in\mathcal C^\infty(X,\Omega_{X,\mathbb C}\otimes\operatorname{End} E)$, called curvature form, such that,
$$(\mathrm d^\nabla)^2s=\Theta\wedge s\qquad\forall s\in\mathcal C^\infty(X,\Omega_{X,\mathbb C}^k\otimes E)$$
The curvature form $\Theta$ locally can be written as,
$$\Theta=\Theta^\beta_{i\bar j\alpha}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j\otimes e^\alpha\otimes e_\beta\tag3$$
I want to write $\Theta^\beta_{i\bar j\alpha}$ in terms of Christoffel symbols. I try this like the following:
\begin{align*}
\Theta_\alpha^\beta &= \mathrm d\omega_\alpha^\beta - \omega_\alpha^\gamma\wedge \omega_\gamma^\beta\\
&= \mathrm d\left(\Gamma^\beta_{i\alpha}dz^i+\Gamma^\beta_{\bar i\alpha}d\bar z^i\right)-\left(\Gamma^\gamma_{i\alpha}dz^i+\Gamma^\gamma_{\bar i\alpha}d\bar z^i\right)\wedge\left(\Gamma^\beta_{j\gamma}dz^j+\Gamma^\beta_{\bar j\gamma}d\bar z^j\right)\\
&=\partial_j\Gamma^\beta_{i\alpha}dz^j\wedge dz^i+\partial_{\bar j}\Gamma^\beta_{i\alpha}d\bar z^j\wedge dz^i+\partial_j\Gamma^\beta_{\bar i\alpha}dz^j\wedge d\bar z^i+\partial_{\bar j}\Gamma^\beta_{\bar i\alpha}d\bar z^j\wedge d\bar z^i\\
&\qquad-\Gamma^\gamma_{i\alpha}\Gamma^\beta_{j\gamma}dz^i\wedge dz^j-\Gamma^\gamma_{i\alpha}\Gamma^\beta_{\bar j\gamma}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j
-\Gamma^\gamma_{\bar i\alpha}\Gamma^\beta_{j\gamma}d\bar z^i\wedge dz^j-\Gamma^\gamma_{\bar i\alpha}\Gamma^\beta_{\bar j\gamma}d\bar z^i\wedge d\bar z^j\\
&\stackrel{\star}{=} \partial_j \Gamma^\beta_{i\alpha}dz^j\wedge dz^i-\Gamma^\gamma_{i\alpha}\Gamma^\beta_{j\gamma}dz^i\wedge dz^j+\boxed{\partial_{\bar j}\Gamma^\beta_{i\alpha}d\bar z^j\wedge dz^i}
\end{align*}
$\star$: we know that Christoffel symbols which contain only pure indices are non-vanishing. $\Gamma^\gamma_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\Gamma^{\bar\gamma}_{\overline{\alpha\beta}}$. But while verifying my result I found that,

$$\Theta_h=\Theta^\gamma_{i\bar j\alpha}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j\otimes e^\alpha\otimes e_\gamma,\qquad\boxed{\Theta^\gamma_{i\bar j\alpha}=-\frac{\partial\Gamma^{\gamma}_{i\alpha}}{\partial\bar z^j}}$$


Question 1: How did they further simplify the result? I see the boxed part is correct. But how the other terms vanish also?

Motivating from here I write the curvature as:
$$R=R^\beta_{i\bar j\alpha}dz^i\otimes d\bar z^j\otimes e^\alpha\otimes e_\beta\tag4$$
I also try to write it in terms of the Christoffel symbol [I will update my computation].

Question 2: Though I understand some of these calculations but still couldn't understand fully the relation between the curvature form $(2)$ and curvature tensor $(4)$. It will be a great help if anyone shares some insight.

Thanks in advance.
